# Show array values using foreach inside template file in block in module development in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I created a custom module to create a block programmatically and show country list. It uses custom template file. I passed the country list array to the template file.

Issue is how do I show each country using foreach inside the template file.

My code is given below.

my_web_service.module

```
    <?php

    /*
     * @file
     * A sample web service module
     */

    /*
     * Implements hook_menu
     */

    function my_web_service_menu() {
      $items = array();

      $items['test-web-service'] = array(
        'title' => 'Test Web Service',
        'description' => 'Test web service',    
        'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
      );

      return $items;
    }

    function my_web_service_consume_data() {
      $url = 'http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all';
      $result = drupal_http_request($url);
      $country_response = drupal_json_decode($result->data);
      $country = array();
      $i = 0;
      if (!empty($country_response)) {
        foreach($country_response['RestResponse']['result'] as $country_arr) {
          $country[$i] = $country_arr['name'];
          $i++;
        }
      }

      return $country; 
    }

    function my_web_service_block_info() {
      $blocks['my_web_service'] = array(
        'info' => t('My Web Service'),
      );

      return $blocks;
    }

    function my_web_service_block_view($delta = '') {
      switch ($delta) {
        case 'my_web_service' :
          $block['subject'] = t('My Web Service');
          if (user_access('access content')) {
            $result = my_web_service_consume_data();
            $variables = $result;
            //$block['content'] = theme('item_list', array('items' => $result)); 
            $block['content'] = theme('block__my_web_service', $variables);
            //$block['content'] = theme('item_list', $variables);
          }
      } 

      return $block;

}
function my_web_service_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $theme = array();
  $theme['block__my_web_service'] = array(
    'variables' => array(),
    'template' => 'block--my_web_service',    
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_web_service') . '/templates',
  );
  return $theme;
}
```

template/block--my_web_service.tpl

```
<?php
echo '<pre>' . print_r($variables, true) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Please find the screen shot of out put below.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVl9I.jpg)

**References**

*[Create a custom template file for a custom block in drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570599/create-a-custom-template-file-for-a-custom-block-in-drupal)*

*https://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/custom-drupal-blocks-right-way*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed a few issues in your code:

1. Your `hook_theme` implementation is incomplete. Final code:

   ```
   function my_web_service_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
      $theme = array();
      $theme['block__my_web_service'] = array(
        'variables' => array(
           'results' => array()
         ),
        'template' => 'block--my_web_service',    
        'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_web_service') . '/templates',
      );
      return $theme;
    }
   ```
2. Call your theme like this:

   ```
    ...
    $result = my_web_service_consume_data();
    $variables = array(
        'results' => $result
    );
    $block['content'] = theme('block__my_web_service', $variables);
   ```
3. Use `$results` variable in your template:

   ```
    <?php
     foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo $result . '<br/>';
     }
    ?>
   ```

That's pretty much it. Good luck.

Comment: I followed as you suggested. In template file I var_dump it. It gives me NULL.  var_dump($results)

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: results in include() (line 2 of D:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-7-sandbox\sites\all\modules\custom\my_web_service\templates\block--my_web_service.tpl.php).

Comment: Did you cleared your cache ? Just tested my code and it works pretty well on my side.

Comment: Thanks Claudiu for your reply. Sorry for late comment actually it is working with below change.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = my_web_service_consume_data();
 $variables = array(
     'results' => $results
 );
 $block['content'] = theme('block__my_web_service', $variables);
```

Note that it should be $results instead of $result